# Is 'user-scalable=no' broken with iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

The following markup is so simple, I'm baffled as to why I'm able to scale in Safari on iPhone 4 when I shouldn't be able to. Any idea what I might be missing, or if this is a bug?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body { padding:0; margin:0; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<a href="example.html"><img src="splash.jpg" width="640" height="960" alt="Click"></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'm experiencing the exact same issue on my up-to-date iPod touch. None of the parameter combinations or answers in this thread worked. According to Apple's documentation I'm using the right code. Also, important to note that the parameter "initial-scale" does work, so the meta tag is being read by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem, some pages did work but my own not.

The Problem is the framing. If you frame the content (e.g. frame-forwarding by domain host) then the meta-tags aren't used.

There was my fault yesterday when I tried programming a WebApp.

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had to set width to be device-width but I might be wrong.

Comment: You can set anything, as far as I know. I tried device-width, but I'm getting the same problem: I can scale. I found a post on the Apple dev forums that indicate someone else having the same problem as me, but fixed it by restoring. No way I'm doing that.

Comment: Ah, apologies that it didn't help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're using xhtml closing tags, get rid of them and likely it will work. If not, add a `preventDefault()` handler to the body tag.

**Note:** Adding `preventDefault();` will disable vertical scrolling as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're aiming for here but if you want your page to go full-width (and no more) in both landscape and portrait view then try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;"/>
```